# How can I not combine the padding, margin styles in the Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I not combine the padding, margin styles in the vue? **Paddings are set dynamically**.

```
:style="['padding-top: 3px', 'padding-right: 32px', 'padding-bottom: 3px', 'padding-left: 32px']"
```

generates:

```
<div style="padding: 3px 32px"></div>
```

need:

```
<div style="padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 32px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 32px"></div>
```

Comment: Probably some PostCSS/minification of some sort. How is it an issue to have a shorter form? It will do the same at the end, maybe a tidy better performance-wise.

Comment: I need pure html for further use, where padding: 3px 32px padding: 3px 32px 3px, etc. are not supported

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here but it looks quite hacky.

Answer (score 3):

You've written that your code contains `padding-left: 32px`, which along with `padding-right: 32px` means the generated styling can just use shorthand `padding: 0px 32px` (0px top and bottom, 32px left and right) but then you say you need `padding-left: 0px`.  What you want is in direct opposition to what you've coded.
Change your code to match what you want

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the question, but the essence remains, I need vue not to use shorthand.

Comment: It is not possible because the shorthand is generated on render.  If for some reason the styling was changed dynamically and say padding-left changed to `0px`, the component would rerender without the shorthand.  There is no reason to stop shorthand CSS from being generated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use classes instead, and you need to make a separate class for each thing that you want to keep separate.

I do not know your motivation to do this is, but I am guessing you are creating some sort of customizable UI component where the user can change padding reactively for some reason (my best guess).

Here is how you add `padding` dynamically as css variables by binding the `style` attribute.

```html
<template>
  <div :style="customVariables"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
//...
const pLeft = ref("32px");
const pRight = ref("20px");

const customVariables= computed(() => {
  return {
    "--p-left": pLeft.value,
    "--p-right": pRight.value,
}
//...
</script>

<style>
.p-left {
  padding-left: var(--p-left);
}

.p-right {
  padding-right: var(--p-right);
}
</style>
```

---

Vue also supports `v-bind()` in CSS. [Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css)

```html
<script setup>
const paddings = {
  pLeft: '32px',
  pRight: '20px'
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="p-left p-right">hello</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.p-left {
 padding-left: v-bind("paddings.pLeft");
}

.p-right {
 padding-right: v-bind("paddings.pRight");
</style>
```

The values provided to CSS through `v-bind` will be **reactive** as explained in the docs:

> The actual value will be compiled into a hashed CSS custom property, so the CSS is still static. The custom property will be applied to the component's root element via inline styles and **reactively updated** if the source value changes.

---

If you want to do so without using classes, then there is no way to do it, and honestly there is no real application/reason of forcing yourself to do it using "style" attribute.

Comment: Paddings are set dynamically

Comment: @SergsIll answering some answers/comments could help you move forward overall.

Comment: Then you can use either computed variables that can be used in CSS, or use v-bind in css: Documentation: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css:~:text=classes%27)-,v%2Dbind()%20in%20CSS,-%23 .

Comment: Updated my answer to adjust dynamic paddings.

Comment: Your option is good. But I need pure html for further use, where padding: 3px 32px padding: 3px 32px 3px, etc. are not supported.

Comment: I am afraid that we do not have enough information to provide you the answer. We at least need the use case (what you are trying to do) to point you in the right direction.